# prevent firefox from using gnome theme's colour scheme for websites

Tags: firefox, css

this topic has been discussed several times, the solution is to edit chrome/userContent.css and add default colours there. but unfortunately I know nothing about css files, what possibilities do I have there? for example I created a website with a text-editor and no info on colours in it. then my userContent.css looks like that:

```
* {color: black ; background: #aaaaaa ; }
```

works great on my website, but every other website probably defined colours in their own stylesheet globally for the page to inherit it. so, I'm asking: does css format know something that's the absolute opposite of "!important"? i.e. I want to tell firefox to use my defaults only when the defaults provided by my browser would be used, and not to overwrite what the creator of a webpage has declared to be default. anyone with some knowledge on css files here? guess I need to replace the "*" by something meaningful, but I don't know what. "INPUT, TEXTAREA" is too restrictive, I want every text-content to default to my choice if none is given.

of course, another way would be to alter the sourcecode of firefox itself, so it stops using theme-colours in webpages and uses hardcoded defaults. does such a patch already exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to go to Edit -> Preferences -> Content -> Colors. The colors you choose there will not override site colors, but options are limited. There is also a checkbox here that will allow sites to set their own coors, and one to use system colors. These checkboxes sound like they will help you.

You can also go to `about:config` and search for "color" to find all default colors that Firefox uses (which you can change to any hexadecimal values), and color-related options like the ones controlled by those checkboxes.

Comment: And delete userContent.css. That thing is useless.

Comment: thanks, that solved my problem! I just unchecked the "use system colours", and my chosen defaults get used.